# How to pass Data from UICollectionView selected cell to TabBarController with two other ViewControllers

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a **VC (mainVC)** with **scrollView** which has **multiple collectionViews** (as sections), each collectionView has **multiple cells**. For each cell I have different values in arrays, which I would like to show in another VC (**tableViewController**), connected to **TabBarController**.

The mainVC is connected through segue (not through cell).

I have implemented **prepare(for segue: )** function, how ever I am able via **if collection.tag == Int** pass array to all of the cells tapped (obviously). So the data is passing correctly, I just can't figure out how to implement indexPath.item to properly present data in tableView for selected cell.

For example: collection1 -> cell[0] -> tableview(array1), collection1 -> cell[1] -> tableview(array2), collection2 -> cell[0] -> tableview(array3) and so on.

I tried many different ways, even via didSelectItemAt with switch statement with case for every Collection view and IndexPath.Item and IndexPath.Row too, but Data shouldn't be passed this way (?)

The code:

`var skuskaValues1:NSArray = ["Skuska 1A", "Skuska 1B", "Skuska 1C"]`

`var skuskaValues2:NSArray = ["Skuska 2A", "Skuska 2B", "Skuska 2C"]`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    
    if segue.identifier == "Skuska" {


        if collectionView.tag == 0 {

        }
       if collectionView.tag == 1 {

        }


    }
}
```

**In didSelectItemAt:**

```
let VC1 = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! SkuskaTableViewController

switch collectionView {
    case basicsCollectionView:
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:


            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Skuska", sender: collectionView)
            VC1.skuskaValues = skuskaValues1 as! [String]

        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Skuska", sender: collectionView)
            VC1.skuskaValues = skuskaValues2 as! [String]
        default:
            print("something")
        }
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring your `VC1` on your `didSelectItemAt`, you should do it on your `prepare(for segue:)`

e.g.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Skuska" {
            if let destVC = segue.destination as! YourViewControler {
                destVC.yourVariable = valueYouWantToPass
            }
        }
    }
```